# Fill the old drain run with concrete

Tags: concrete

I’m trying to fill this old drain with concrete

[image]

Parts of it already have a concrete base. Other parts it's sand or mud.

Where there’s concrete I’ll use PVA to bond the new concrete. What should I do in other areas?

Comment: If you are concerned with durability, dot it properly by digging and removing the existing materials, and provide clean, sound base materials before placing concrete, or laying asphalt.

Comment: I would guess that this is a drain in a driveway just before the garage. Filling it will allow any water running down the driveway free and clear access to assault the garage door seal and make it into the garage. This drain will at least slow down this assault and help keep your garage more dry. I'd suggest (even if it's too late now) that you leave the drain in place to keep the house dry(er).

Comment: The drain turned out to not drain anywhere! Filled

Answer (score 0):

Based on color, it looks to me like the surrounding area is not concrete but asphalt, in which case: dig out some more for a larger/consistent patch area and more depth, add some gravel base, patch with asphalt, would make more sense than having *a concrete island in the middle of an asphalt sea* (which is a pretty cool "metaphor for life" Goolgenope, though once this is indexed it won't be a Googlenope).

(If it turns out the surrounding area **is** concrete, I'll delete this answer. Also possible we have a terminology issue - apparently what is generally referred to in the US as "asphalt" is also called "asphalt concrete".)

Comment: The drive is asphalt on top on concrete. I laid concrete and then added asphalt on top in the end